# python: how to use \G in regular expression to search from previous match point

Tags: python, regex

Am trying to search objects in a string and , i want to make the next search based on the previous match point.
I want to use \G to get the previous match point(to learn to use '\G')

```
a='hello'
match = re.search(r'e',a,re.M|re.I)
match1 = re.search(r'\G\w',a,re.M|re.I)
print match.group()
print match1.group()
```

am expecting the second match 'l'

here am not getting a match

Comment: Python doesn't support that regex feature.  `\G` has no special meaning in a Python regex.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm

Comment: Apparently that page is wrong.  See [the actual documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Comment: Take a look a the [PyPi regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) package, it does support `\G` - but it does not work the way you show in your code.

Comment: There is a way to simulate this with `re`. I will close as a dupe once I find nhahtdh answer. Found, closed.